# how to dynamically change the gridview rows and columns in Android

Tags: android, gridview

I am using Gridview in my activity.I am also having a CustomGridAdpater to show the image and textview on each grid.

Upon launching my activity. I neeed to dynamically create grid rows and column depending upon the values.

```
count = 4   2x2 grid
count = 9   3x3 grid
count = 16  4x4 grid
```

Please tell me how i can achieve this functionality.

my Gridview:

```
 <GridView
        android:id="@+id/Favorite_GridView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/Date_RelativeLayout"           
        android:listSelector="@drawable/gridview_norecode_selector"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"                  />
```

I have made the columns android:numColumns="auto_fit" 
So it default to 2 columns.

I am also having a Custom GridAdapter

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/grid_color_selector" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
   android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
   android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
   />        
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Day_TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/gridview_line_norecord"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:text="Hello" />
```

I also used this function inside my activity

```
  if(newList.length > 4)
    {
        mgridView.setColumnWidth(350);

    }
```

But i am worried about giving values manually inside the activity. As i feel it may give abnormal UI for landscape mode.

Please help me how to proceed.

Comment: Have you tried `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager`?

Answer (score 0):

hoomi's comment is right.

use RecyclerView and GridLayoutManager.! 
in .xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/gridview_horizontal_spacing"
            android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/gridview_vertical_spacing"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView" />
```

and 
`recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context , number));`

or

`gridview.setNumColumns(number);`